# Why in Rocksmith score attack, even I got 100% and platinum pick, I'm not in first place?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I'm trying to be 1st place in leaderboards in Score Attack for the song Have You Ever Seen The Rain from CCW.

I have achieved to have 100% of the song and got platinum pick and I'm still in 9th place.

The multiplier can't be the problem, since I have made all single notes correctly.

What other variables are giving those people ahead me more points?

The multiplier or score is affected for Perfect Phrases?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on PC, do you see the other 8 people's scores ? It is very possible they have a score of 2147483647 which is not achieved trough fair means.

Comment: @ИвоНедев [A bit of trivia about the high score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)#In_computing). But this is not restricted to PC gaming. I have seen this before on console as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the score attack, the game recognizes three types of correct notes which you can possibly hit. It is "perfect", "good" and "too early" (this appears at the side of your screen whenever you hit a correct note). All of them count as correct, so at the end of a song you achieve 100% accuracy. But if there is a person with a higher amount of perfect notes than you, you will not be in the 1st place in the leaderboard, since perfect notes receive more score points than good notes and notes played too early.

You can hit perfect notes by playing notes exactly on time, whereas too early or good notes mean that you hit them some milliseconds before or after the point that you actually should play them (but it is still not so early/late to miss it).